# Referencing generic list of grouped items in XAML

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use a grouped list of FoodItems

**Model**

```
[Table("FoodItems")]
public class Food
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]                        // Primary Key combined with ID
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

**ContentView XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             x:DataType="viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Views.FoodsOverviewView">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">

        <StackLayout Padding="10">

            <SearchBar Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  Placeholder="{loc:Translate SearchFoodItemPlaceholder}" Text="{Binding SearchText}" />

            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" HeightRequest="600" IsGrouped="True">

                <!--Group Header showing Headings for a Group and a box-->
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedFoodItemList">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type models:Food}">
                        <SwipeView>

                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems>

                                    <!--We need the suffix ..Command in the Name as it will be generated like this with the MVVM Toolkit-->
                                    <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate SwipeItemDeleteFoodItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" 
                                       Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteFoodItemCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                    <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate SwipeItemEditFoodItem}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" 
                                       Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=EditFoodItemCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>

                            <Grid Padding="0, 5">
                                <Frame>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </Frame>
                            </Grid>

                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

**GroupedFoodItemList**

```
public partial class GroupedFoodItemList : List<Food>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public GroupedFoodItemList(string groupName, List<Food> foodItem) : base(foodItem)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public partial class FoodsOverviewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Food> FoodItems { get; set; }


    public FoodsOverviewViewModel()
    {
        FoodItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<Food>();

        ...
    }

    private async Task RefreshFromDataBase()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await Task.Delay(500);

        FoodItems.Clear();
        var foodItems = await DatabaseService.GetFoodItems();
        FoodItems.AddRange(foodItems);

        GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter();       // Start with empty Search-Filter (=> get all Items)

        IsBusy = false;
    }


    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set
        {
            if (_searchText != value)
            {
                _searchText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                OnSearchTextChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSearchTextChanged()
    {
        GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter();
    }

    
    private ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList> _groupedFoodItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList> GroupedFoodItems
    {
        get => _groupedFoodItems != null ? _groupedFoodItems : new ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList>();
        set
        {
            if (_groupedFoodItems != value)
            {
                _groupedFoodItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedFoodItems));
            }
        }
    }

    private void GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter()
    {
        IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<Food>>> groupedFoodItemsDictionary;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            groupedFoodItemsDictionary = FoodItems
                .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name)
                .GroupBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
        }
        else
        {
            groupedFoodItemsDictionary = FoodItems
                .Where(food => food.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()))
                .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name)
                .GroupBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
        }

        GroupedFoodItems.Clear();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Food>> item in groupedFoodItemsDictionary)
        {
            GroupedFoodItems.Add(new GroupedFoodItemList(item.Key, new List<Food>(item.Value)));
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is currently working fine for me. But, I need this GroupedFoodItemList in different places and different Data Types, not only with Type **Food** from my Model.

So, I thought of making this a generic list like:

```
public partial class GroupedItemList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public GroupedItemList(string groupName, List<T> item) : base(item)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

When I do this, I can't reference this list anymore in XAML. Basically, I don't know how to do this correctly and reference the **GroupName** from the corresponding typed list of the genereric **GroupedItemList**.

How do I have to do this?

======= Edit: Added non working Code =======

**Generic for GroupedItem**

```
public partial class GroupedItemList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public GroupedItemList(string groupName, List<T> item) : base(item)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel using generic GroupedItem List of type Foor**

```
public partial class FoodsOverviewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Food> FoodItems { get; set; }


    public FoodsOverviewViewModel()
    {
        FoodItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<Food>();

        ...
    }

    private async Task RefreshFromDataBase()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await Task.Delay(500);

        FoodItems.Clear();
        var foodItems = await DatabaseService.GetFoodItems();
        FoodItems.AddRange(foodItems);

        GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter();       // Start with empty Search-Filter (=> get all Items)

        IsBusy = false;
    }


    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set
        {
            if (_searchText != value)
            {
                _searchText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                OnSearchTextChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSearchTextChanged()
    {
        GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter();
    }

    
    private ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList<Food>> _groupedFoodItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList<Food>> GroupedFoodItems
    {
        get => _groupedFoodItems != null ? _groupedFoodItems : new ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedFoodItemList<Food>>();
        set
        {
            if (_groupedFoodItems != value)
            {
                _groupedFoodItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupedFoodItems));
            }
        }
    }

    private void GroupFoodsWithSearchFilter()
    {
        IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<Food>>> groupedFoodItemsDictionary;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            groupedFoodItemsDictionary = FoodItems
                .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name)
                .GroupBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
        }
        else
        {
            groupedFoodItemsDictionary = FoodItems
                .Where(food => food.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchText.ToLower()))
                .OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name)
                .GroupBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Substring(0, 1))
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()).OrderBy(group => group.Key);
        }

        GroupedFoodItems.Clear();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Food>> item in groupedFoodItemsDictionary)
        {
            GroupedFoodItems.Add(new GroupedFoodItemList(item.Key, new List<Food>(item.Value)));
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView XAML using the generic GroupedItem List**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             x:DataType="viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Views.FoodsOverviewView">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">

        <StackLayout Padding="10">

            <SearchBar Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"  Placeholder="{loc:Translate SearchFoodItemPlaceholder}" Text="{Binding SearchText}" />

            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" HeightRequest="600" IsGrouped="True">

                <!--Group Header showing Headings for a Group and a box-->
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedItemList`1[models:Food]">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="{StaticResource Gray200}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type models:Food}">
                        <SwipeView>

                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems>

                                    <!--We need the suffix ..Command in the Name as it will be generated like this with the MVVM Toolkit-->
                                    <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate SwipeItemDeleteFoodItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" 
                                       Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteFoodItemCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                    <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate SwipeItemEditFoodItem}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" 
                                       Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:FoodsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=EditFoodItemCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>

                            <Grid Padding="0, 5">
                                <Frame>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </Frame>
                            </Grid>

                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

In XAML he doesn’t know the GroupName anymore and can’t access it in the generic List.

Comment: Are you specifying the TypeArguments? Do not show me the working code, show me the one that has problems.

Comment: I have added some Code to my question

Comment: What is this? [models:Food]. Remove it.

Comment: Well this is as something that came out when searching for a solution and anybody used ot like this. I don’t know, how to tell XAML that this is currently a GroupedItemList<Food> and Food is in Namespace models

Comment: If you want to specify Food, you do something like FoodGroup : Group<Food>. And then work with FoodGroup. I am not sure you can specify the Food otherwise. To be honest, even the Generic is long shot.

Comment: Remove this  [models:Food], as I told you and test. Good idea is to test in release, because in Debug, for some reason it "finds" the fields anyway. So if you want to be sure that it works, it has to be in release.

Comment: I don’t know, if I got you right: you are advising not to use generic lists at all and use different lists for each data type? Or would it work to just use the x:DataType put o the „`1“ and ```x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedItemList`1“```? Does it have to be „`2“ for the next generic type then or how could XAML know which actual type I want to use?

Comment: `1 , `2 and so on, show you how many generic inner Types you use.

Comment: My problem with generics is that no matter how crappy your code is, even if you totally mess up your DataType, the code will work perfectly in debug. While it release it will start showing empty spaces. And you may be unable to fix it. And then you may have to redesign it, at the worst possible moment. This is why I say, FoodGroup : Group<Food> is better solution. Whatever you decide to do, please test in Release mode only!!!

Comment: Okay, testing it in Release is a good hint and I will do that. My purpose to migrate it to a generic was that the very same GroupedItem list should be used with different types (e.g. Food and totally different with Person). So based on the type I started to create a 2nd list like that and thought this is not good to do. So with your proposal it would be like that or did I get you wrong

Comment: More or less. The bonus here is that you will be inheriting from Group<T> instead of List<T>.  Today you have Name property. Tomorrow you may have Color. And you add this property only in one class. Not in 10 or 100. And I guarantee that this will work. While in generics, I am not even sure that it is possible. Despite working in debug...

Comment: Okay, I can consider using Group<T> as you argued. For understanding purposes, „`1“, „`2“, … is how many „inner types“ are used. Meaning, when I use GroupedItemList with „Food“ and „Person“ I would need to change it in all places from „`1“ to „`2“ and for the next type to „`3“??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253336/discussion-between-h-a-h-and-oxo).

Comment: Sorry, can’t comment in chat on my mobil: I do not understand why I don’t use it? Group<T> : List<T> is the actual generic typed list. The actual FoodGroup (which then should be of type Group<Food>) is an Observable Property and used there. The group is used to have a grouped CollectionView and I display groups like „A“, „B“, … and so on and displayed all FoodItems that start with that GroupName. So, it is actually a Dictionary of GroupName and List<Food> in the end. At least that was my purpose with that code and how it is displayed in the CollectionView (without introduction of the generic).

Comment: No, FoodGroup is a type itself, not object of type. This is specific. Unlike the type Group<T>, it no longer uses generics. So now you can set the type FoodGroup as a DataType.